# Spark : How do I exploded data and add column name also in pyspark or scala spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

Spark: I want explode multiple columns and consolidate as single column with column name as separate row.

```
Input data: 
    +-----------+-----------+-----------+
    |   ASMT_ID |   WORKER  |   LABOR   |
    +-----------+-----------+-----------+
    |   1       |   A1,A2,A3|   B1,B2   |
    +-----------+-----------+-----------+
    |   2       |   A1,A4   |   B1      |
    +-----------+-----------+-----------+

Expected Output:


+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|   ASMT_ID |WRK_CODE   |WRK_DETL   |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|   1       |   A1      |   WORKER  |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|   1       |   A2      |   WORKER  |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|   1       |   A3      |   WORKER  |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|   1       |   B1      |   LABOR   |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|   1       |   B2      |   LABOR   |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|   2       |   A1      |   WORKER  |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|   2       |   A4      |   WORKER  |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|   2       |   B1      |   LABOR   |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

[PFA: Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvKeO.jpg)

Comment: Post the code you tried, At least like loading the data into spark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the best case probably but a couple of `explode`s and `unionAll` is all you need.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df1.show
+-------+--------+-----+
|ASMT_ID|  WORKER|LABOR|
+-------+--------+-----+
|      1|A1,A2,A3|B1,B2|
|      2|   A1,A4|   B1|
+-------+--------+-----+

df1.cache

val workers = df1.drop("LABOR")
                 .withColumn("WRK_CODE" , explode(split($"WORKER" , ",") ) )
                 .withColumn("WRK_DETL", lit("WORKER"))
                 .drop("WORKER")

val labors = df1.drop("WORKER")
                .withColumn("WRK_CODE" , explode(split($"LABOR", ",") ) )
                .withColumn("WRK_DETL", lit("LABOR") )
                .drop("LABOR")

workers.unionAll(labors).orderBy($"ASMT_ID".asc , $"WRK_CODE".asc).show

+-------+--------+--------+
|ASMT_ID|WRK_CODE|WRK_DETL|
+-------+--------+--------+
|      1|      A1|  WORKER|
|      1|      A2|  WORKER|
|      1|      A3|  WORKER|
|      1|      B1|   LABOR|
|      1|      B2|   LABOR|
|      2|      A1|  WORKER|
|      2|      A4|  WORKER|
|      2|      B1|   LABOR|
+-------+--------+--------+
```